# Applying patches to Octave on Windows

Tags: octave, patch

I want to fix the Octave breakpoint bug on windows. I found the patch in the bug tracker **[[bug #46451]](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?46451)** but I can't seem to find a way to apply it on windows. I can see the diff files to be changed, but even then i can't seem to find the files within octave folder to apply the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the patch changes C++ source code you have to build GNU Octave yourself. The windows build are nowadays done with MXE octave http://wiki.octave.org/MXE which is a crosscompile environment.

In a nutshell you have to

1. Install a GNU/Linux distribution
2. Install built dependencies, mercurial and so on
3. Clone the mxe octave repo
4. Perhaps adapt the patch to the current sourceode and apply it
5. Built MXE Octave which takes some hours